# Good way to cache data during Android application lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

keeping my question short, I have created an application with 3 activities, where A - list of categories, B - list of items, C - single item. Data displayed in B and C is parsed from online XML. But, if I go through A -> B1 -> C, then back to A and then back to B1, I would like to have its data cached somewhere so I wouldn't have to request the XML again.

I'm new to Android and Java programming, I've googled a lot and still can't find (or simply do not have an idea where to look) a way to do what I want.

Would storing all received data in main activity A (HashMaps? ContentProviders?) and then passing to B and C (if they get same request that was before) be a good idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple and fast way to cache information or to keep track of the application state, is to extend the *Application* as described in [this blog post](http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/126377651/global-application-state-in-android).

This blog post forgets to add that you have to set your *CustomApplication* class in the manifest, like:

```
<application [...] android:name="CustomApplication">
```

In my projects I stick to the singleton style via getInstance.

More resources: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android), [Global Variables in Android Apps](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7778) and [this blog post](http://www.bryandenny.com/index.php/2010/05/25/what-i-learned-from-writing-my-first-android-application/).

Comment: Thanks your the first person to talk about the manifest, I think not adding it causes a cast exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build some sort of cache on memory, consider using a Map with SoftReferences. SoftReferences are sort of references that tend to keep your data around for a while, but does not prevent it from being garbage collected.

Memory on a cell phone is scarce, so keeping everything in memory may not be practical. In that case you may want to save your caches on the device's secondary storage.

Check out MapMaker from [Google's Collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), which allows you to conveniently build a 2-level cache. Consider doing this:

```
/** Function that attempts to load data from a slower medium */
Function<String, String> loadFunction = new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String key) {
        // maybe check out from a slower cache, say hard disk
        // if not available, retrieve from the internet
        return result;
    }
};

/** Thread-safe memory cache. If multiple threads are querying
*   data for one SAME key, only one of them will do further work.
*   The other threads will wait. */
Map<String, String> memCache = new MapMaker()
                                .concurrentLevel(4)
                                .softValues()
                                .makeComputingMap(loadFunction);
```

About cache on device's secondary storage, check out [Context.getCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()). If you're sloppy like me, just leave everything there and hope that the system will clean things for you when it needs more space :P

Comment: I think this is the right way but kinda old... Any new findings about app 2-level + storage cache?

Comment: As the [official Android API documentation for SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) explains, it's not a good idea to use SoftReferences to build a cache.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of data storage as explained in Android Reference here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: It's an option, but I'll have to worry about flushing data at the end of application lifetime?

Comment: isnt it a good idea to keep data cached even after the end of app lifetime ?

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged.